# How to replace a part of user input with another user input?

Tags: java, regex, replace

I'm making a text editor that has to run with cmd. The user pastes in a text they want to edit, then they choose what exactly they want to do with it. I struggle with replacing a part of the text they pasted in.

This is (a part of) my code for the editor:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class TextEd {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Editor editor = new Editor();
        editor.copiedText();
    }
}
class Editor {
    
    private Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    private String text = " ";
    
    public void copiedText() {
    
        System.out.println("Paste your text here.");        //The user input
        text = scan.nextLine();
        menu();
    }

    public void menu() {
    
        System.out.println("Welcome to the text editor.\n"
            + "What do you wish to do?\n"
            + "1. Replace a word/line.\n"
            + "2. Exit program.");
        int choice = scan.nextInt();
    
        if (choice == 1) {
            replacing();
        }
        else if (choice == 2) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the code for the replacing part, where I struggle:

```
public void replacing() {    //still not working argh
    
    String replacement = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What dou you want to replace?");
    try {
        Pattern replacepat = Pattern.compile(scan.next());
        Matcher match = replacepat.match(text);
        System.out.println("What dou you want to replace it with?");
        scan.nextLine();
    
        boolean found = false;
        while (match.find()) {
            text = text.replaceAll(replacepat, replacement);
            System.out.println(text);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) { 
        System.out.println("There's been an error.");
    }
}
```

The errors I get inform me, that the Pattern cannot be converted to String - which I understand, replaceAll works with int - but I have no idea how to get the index of the text the user wants to replace, because the user's job is to paste the text in and then the other part of the text they want to replace.

Comment: Please make a [mre], quote the errors, provide sample input and desired output/result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replaceAll will compile the first parameter as a regex (see javadoc)
So you just have to provide the regex as string:

```
public void replacing() {    //still not working argh
    
    System.out.println("What dou you want to replace?");
    try {
        String findText=scan.next();
        System.out.println("What dou you want to replace it with?");
        String newText=scan.next();
    
        text = text.replaceAll(findText, newText);
        System.out.println(text);
    }
    catch (Exception e) { 
        System.out.println("There's been an error.");
    }
}
```

From javadoc:

```
An invocation of this method of the form str.replaceAll(regex, repl) yields 
exactly the same result as the expression 

java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str).replaceAll(repl)
```